# How to use Regexp.new() in Ruby to search for Integer value in DB?

Tags: javascript, ruby, mongodb, autocomplete

I have some code in my controller which functions as a search in the database (mongo) :

```
@job_results = Job.where({:merchant_id => admin,:$or => [
                        {:job_number => Regexp.new(/#{key.to_i}/x)},
                        {:type => Regexp.new(/^#{key}/i)},
                        {:status => Regexp.new(/^#{key}/i)}
                    ]})
```

The `job_number` is stored as an Integer value in the DB and unfortunately cannot be changed:

```
  key :job_number, Integer
```

When I run the query directly in mongo, it returns:

```
> db.jobs.find( { job_number: 2013058 } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519555d789651a5443000346"), "job_number" : 2013058, "type" : "5191027089651a5adb000093", "priority" : "5191027b89651a5d38000001", "start_time" : "08:00", "end_time" : "10:00" }
```

However, the search doesn't return any results:

```
MONGODB (0.5ms) DATABASE['jobs'].find({:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013", :$or=>[{:job_number=>/2013058/x}, {:type=>/^2013058/i}, {:status=>/^2013058/i}]})

job_results: Array[0]
```

If I search for a Job Type (string, a word) it works fine. I tried to convert the key into an integer, and Ruby isn't complaining about that. I also tried `key.to_s.to_i`. How do I get Jobs to return when searching using a Job Number?

Comment: Using regex on a integers fields may not really work as explained in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1174. According to that issue, using regex on non-string fields "will be very slow, and kind of misleading."

Comment: merchant_id needs to be specified like this `BSON::ObjectId.from_string("518b762e89651a0389000013")`

Answer (score 0):

According to nyde1319 comment on my question, trying to Regex an integer is just no good.  I finally gave up and converted it to a string.  This works for the search.

I'd like to give nyde1319 a +1 but it wasn't an answer - just a comment.

Recap - don't try to Regex.new() against an Integer value.  Use Strings.  If you need to perform mathematical operations against these values AND you want to use autocomplete with Regex for matching - probably best to convert your string to integer for the mathematical operation (.to_i)

Or give up on the searching.  I couldn't make it work.